# Form dropdown goes above the fixed header

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I am using fixed position header for mobile in my wordpress website. But the form dropdown is going above the fixed header. It looks very ugly. I tried to fix it by putting these codes but nothing changed.

`.site-header{position: fixed; width: 100%; z-index:1;}
select{width: 100%; z-index:2;}`

You can go to my website and see the problem.

`www.store.codebla.com/product-category/mens-fashion/`

This problem is only in mobile because i used fixed header for mobile only. So visit the above link on your mobile phone.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.woocommerce-ordering` (the select lives here) has z-index of 999.

You will need to put your header to 1000 or reduce that z-index.

I recommend coming up with a z-index convention.

e.g. go by 100s, and use 110,120,etc. to manage between layers.

Comment: I dont know much about z-index. I put z-index: 1000 in .site-header. but nothing changed

Comment: change z-index to 1000 for `.site-header` in your CSS. Also, verify the changes and that there is no caching going on.  You can test this in chrome or firefox devtools. Works like a charm!